libcurl, backwards ABI compatibility and runtime overloading vs. LD_PRELOAD/DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES
I am tinkering with the MacPorts "base" layer, in particular the interface that its "Pextlib" package for Tcl provides to libcurl.
MacPorts has an up-to-date port for curl, but its own Pextlib library is linked to the system libcurl for evident reasons. That cripples its connectivity function on older systems (OS X 10.9 has curl 7.30.0 for instance). Curl has quite a few dependencies so rather than including it as a "vendored" package in the "base" source bundle I'm looking at a way to load a newer version of the library dynamically and conditionally. In other words, bootstrap the install with the system libcurl, use that to fetch and install a newer libcurl (built specifically for the purpose and only used by Pextlib) and then use that.
Two questions:

In the Ubuntu 14.04 distro I still use on 1 system I see that the libcurl packaging for curl 7.35.0 provides a libcurl.so.3 symlinked to libcurl.so.4, itself symlinked to libcurl.so.4.3.0 . Of course, the previous curl 8.7.1 provides libcurl.so.4.8.0 .
I have already determined that I can tweak (with install_name_tool or patchelf) Pextlib built against curl 7.x to use curl 8.7.1 without any apparent issues so far (as long as I avoid openssl version clashes). Idem when loading libcurl 8.7.1 through DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES or LD_PRELOAD. Can we take what Ubuntu does as an indication that libcurl does indeed have reliable backwards ABI compatibility?
Initial testing suggests that I can dlopen a (dedicated) newer libcurl from Tcl code running in the Tcl interpreter before the Pextlib package is loaded and that Pextlib will then use that newer libcurl even when it is linked to an older system libcurl. This could provide a very simple to implement mechanism to load a newer libcurl version conditionally (= when available). Much simpler than e.g. rewriting Pextlib to load a libcurl version at runtime itself.
To what extent is this a viable alternative, that will work the same way as using DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES/LD_PRELOAD or using dlopen("libcurl") from within Pextlib itself? (Implementing the latter is always possible as a 2nd step, if deemed the better longterm solution.)

(I'm aware that I'm not showing any code here but I think that is not necessary for this kind of question.)
EDIT: More testing using an actual overload from the Pextlib package's pkgIndex.tcl loader suggests that this idea does not work on Mac. The intended special libcurl is loaded as expected, but doesn't get used; connections to https://curl.se continue to fail for instance. I suspect this may have something to do with 2-level namespaces being used, which tend to disable DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES.
